# How to turn off the "Special Variables" window in Python Console of PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I use Python console in PyCharm, when running the code, there is a "Special Variables" window appears on the right hand side of Python Console, how can I permanently turn it off?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

File > Settings > Build, Execution, Development > Console

Then uncheck the box "Show console variables by default". Apply, Ok, then close your current console and reopen it.

[image]

Comment: this option does not exist for mac :(

Answer (score 2):

File > Settings > Build, Execution, Development > Console